# Change Visibility of Stack Panel inside List view on Mouse Hover

Tags: wpf

Below is my list view

```
 <ListView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" BorderThickness="0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListViewDataTemplate}" x:Name="NewTasks" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTask}"/>
```

Data Template For my list view

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="ListViewDataTemplate">
        <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource ListViewStackPanel}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="UserActions">
                <Image Source="\Images\Edit.png" Height="30" Width="30" cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseUp] = [Action EditTask]"/>
                <Image Source="\Images\Delete.png" Height="15" Width="15" cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseUp] = [Action DeleteTask]"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5" FontSize="20" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Trigger for my stack panel in list view

```
<Style TargetType="StackPanel" x:Key="ListViewStackPanel">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Priority}" Value="Low">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#cccedb" />
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="#083045"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Priority}" Value="Medium">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#fbbf79" />
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="#373c3e"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Priority}" Value="High">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#cd5849" />
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

When mouse is hovered on an item in list view the i want to show user actions for that item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addd `Trigger` to your `DataTemplate` to achieve your requirements.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListViewDataTemplate">
    <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource ListViewStackPanel}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="UserActions" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <Image Source="\Images\Edit.png" Height="30" Width="30" cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseUp] = [Action EditTask]"/>
            <Image Source="\Images\Delete.png" Height="15" Width="15" cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseUp] = [Action DeleteTask]"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5" FontSize="20" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="UserActions" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </Trigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

**My Code**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="600">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="StackPanel" x:Key="ListViewStackPanel">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Priority}" Value="Low">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#cccedb" />
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="#083045"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Priority}" Value="Medium">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#fbbf79" />
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="#373c3e"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Priority}" Value="High">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#cd5849" />
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="White"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="ListViewDataTemplate">
            <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource ListViewStackPanel}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="UserActions" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <Image Source="\Images\Edit.png" Height="30" Width="30"  />
                    <Image Source="\Images\Delete.png" Height="15" Width="15" />
                </StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5" FontSize="20" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="UserActions" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </Trigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ListView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" BorderThickness="0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListViewDataTemplate}" x:Name="NewTasks" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTask}"/>
</Window>
```

Comment: I tried the same but getting the following error 
The attachable property 'Triggers' was not found in type 'DataTemplate'.

Comment: @UdayTeja You are welcome. Could you mark it as an answer then.